# Need to determine at run time which types protobuf-net can serialize/deserialize

Tags: protobuf-net

I provide a library that serializes/deserializes data that is used by other developers I work with. The serialized data is stored in the database along with the type name. I do not control which types my library works with. I use JSON serialization and it works fairly well with small amounts of data. But it is slow when the objects are large such as a list with thousands of items.

I want my library to switch from JSON serialization to protocol buffers for specific types that I define in my library and decorate according to protobuf-net requirements.

So I need to write a function to determine if a type can be serialized. I see that there is a Serializer.NonGeneric.CanSerialize() method. But I need something that will work on generic containers like List. In my database, my type name might look like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyAssembly.Person, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
```

... and from that I need to determine if protobuf-net can deserialize the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to do the trick:

```
public static bool CanSerialize(object obj)
{
    if (obj.GetType().IsGenericType)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments[0];
        return Serializer.NonGeneric.CanSerialize(type);
    }

    return Serializer.NonGeneric.CanSerialize(obj.GetType());
}
```

Marc Gravell if you are reading this, seems like this method should be added to the Serializer class. And thanks for this great library.